# Firebase and redux? Save received data in redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm having a problem with saving the data received from the firebase.

When I was fetching the data from backend with native http calls (I was using redux/redux saga for it) the data was stored correctly in the storage, so if user entered some other component and returned back to the listed data, there was no need to fetch the data once again from the server. It was saved inside redux store.

But since Im using firebase, if user navigates over my application and returns to the component which lists some data from the server, the same data is fetched every time. This is a huge issue.

**Q**: Is there some way to store the data received from firebase call in redux store?

Of course, **I don't want to loose** the *real-time database*. This is a pure awesomeness, that user doesn't have to reload the page to update the content.

Looking forward for any hint or suggestions. Maybe I don't even need redux for it? Maybe firebase provides some mechanism to deal with it? Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Found an outstanding library recently, which solves cases included in my question. If anyone would ask for same thing in the future, here's the library:

https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase